# Calling Pro*c code in another .pc file

Tags: c, oracle, asynchronous, oracle-pro-c

Below is the scenario for my problem for pro*c code.

In my new project previously they used the batches to call the pro*c code. But due to new requirement we need to call the same code from online(forms). They are 4-5 `.pc` files which needs to be called on same action asynchronously.

For above I thought to create another `.pc` file which will call these 4-5 `.pc` files. But I don't know whether we can call one `.pc` file in another `.pc` file. The code which is existing is very huge.

If we can call, can I have some idea how we do that?

Answer (score 0):

Your .pc files which are currently being run as part of the batches will presumably have been compiled into executable binaries that are being run.

This is an Oracle forms question rather than a Pro*C question. You need to work out how to execute these binaries from Oracle forms rather than as part of the batches.

See http://docs.oracle.com/cd/B10501_01/appdev.920/a97269/pc_20exi.htm for information on how you might do that.